# tensorflow does not detect GPUs and Can't complete hello = tf.constant('hello')

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'am use

cuda 11.1

tensorflow 2.4.1

python 3.6.12

numpy 1.16.4

Can't complete `hello = tf.constant('hello')` Errors occur

```
2021-03-07 21:21:56.799062: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
2021-03-07 21:21:56.800126: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.353810: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: GeForce GTX 1050 computeCapability: 6.1
coreClock: 1.493GHz coreCount: 5 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 104.43GiB/s
2021-03-07 21:21:57.353998: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.364724: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublas64_11.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.364898: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cublasLt64_11.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.370873: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cufft64_10.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.372735: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library curand64_10.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.377804: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
2021-03-07 21:21:57.382008: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cusparse64_11.dll
2021-03-07 21:21:57.382892: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
2021-03-07 21:21:57.384941: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
Skipping registering GPU devices...
2021-03-07 21:21:57.393327: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2021-03-07 21:21:57.393735: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1261] Device interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix:
2021-03-07 21:21:57.393849: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1267]
2021-03-07 21:21:57.394400: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_gpu_device.cc:99] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/838g5.png)

And when checking, it turns out that tensorflow does not detect GPUs

```
import tensorflow as tf
print("Num GPUs Available: ", len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))
```

---

```
Num GPUs Available:  0
```

How to fix the situation?

Comment: Lmao yeah this is a horrible issue that occurs wayyy too frequently. To solve this you'll need to manually download all those files which 'could not be found' and paste them in the appropriate cudnn folder

Comment: You can download them from the cuda website, or from sourceforge.net. I ran into the same problem a year ago and took a MONTH to resolve them, so I'll be glad to help out any way I can, just tag me in the comments :)

Comment: @RoboMop I honestly don't understand what exactly I need to download

Comment: You need to install cuda 11.0 and cudnn 8 for cuda 11.0 to make that version of tensorflow work

Comment: @talonmies unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: Try renaming `cusolver64_11.dll` to `cusolver64_10.dll` should solve your issue. Thanks!

Comment: ANSWER: In PATH write C: \ cuda \ bin